# Solutions for $x^y = y^x$

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

It appears from Desmos that $x^y = y^x$ is the union of two functions. Obviously, $x = y$ is the one of these functions. What is the other?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PI1NeGtJo7s&ab_channel=blackpenredpen) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_x%CA%B8_%3D_y%CB%A3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not the graph of another function you’d recognize. But here is an award-winning, absolutely terrific article about that function and so much more:

http://eretrandre.org/rb/files/Knoebel1981_158.pdf